# Typescript - How to use an interface to create a new object conforming to a different structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create an object using default values for an interface, but at the
same time changing the structure of the object. For example, for this interface:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

I want to create an object like this:

```
const person: IPerson = {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
}
```

The only way I found is to add the type for the object to `name` and `age` of
the `IPerson` interface, like so:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string | IProp
  age: number | IProp
}

interface IProp {
  type: any
  required?: boolean
  // ...
}
```

I do not want to change the original interface `IPerson` though. So I was
thinking of something like this:

```
const person: IProperties<IPerson> = {
  // use properties of IPerson to determine which key/value pairs are valid in this object
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I have answered this before .. but finding it is challenging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string
  age: number
}

type IProperties<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: IProp
}

interface IProp {
  type: any
  required?: boolean
  // …
}

const person: IProperties<IPerson> = {
    // …
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it! Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes maybe I misunderstood the question, but wouldn't it be useful for `required` and `type` to be a refection of the actualul type passed in ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, you're right. This is just an example, it doesn't really matter what `required` and `type` is... I just needed a way to have an objects conforming to the keys of the `IPerson` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using conditional types and mapped types.

```
interface IPerson {
name: string
age: number
ocupation?: string
}

type PropertyType<T> = 
    [T] extends [string] ? typeof String :
    [T] extends [number] ? typeof Number :
    [T] extends [Date] ? typeof Date :
    [T] extends [Function] ? typeof Function : // add any other types here
    new (...a:any[]) => T // default must be a constructor for whatever T is 

type IfRequired<T, K extends keyof T, IfYes, IfNo> =
    Pick<T, K> extends Required<Pick<T, K>> ? IfYes : IfNo

type PropertyDefinition<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: {
        type: PropertyType<Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>> // will not work for unions!
        required: IfRequired<T, P, true, false>
    }
}

let personDefinition: PropertyDefinition<IPerson> ={
    age : {
        required: true,
        type: Number
    },
    name: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    },
    ocupation: {
        required: false,
        type: String
    }
}
```

Comment: So this actually checks if, e.g. `age: number` uses `type: Number` in the mapped type?

Comment: The TypeScript syntax can be terrible, but it is a stricter answer than mine.

Comment: @Johannes yup, for `age` the only valid value is `{ type: Number, require: true }` any other value would be a compiler error. I agree with paleo, it may be harder to read as far as syntax goes, his answer is also good just less strict, totally your call which you use :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir This might be a different question, but just for completeness sake: Is it also possible to omit `required` if it's set to false? Because `undefined` is already a falsy value.

Comment: @Johannes this should work %`type PropertyDefinition<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: {
    type: PropertyType<Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>>
  } & IfRequired<T, P, { required: true }, { required?: false }>
}`